# blank line with psql in postgres. How could I remove it?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I do a simple query in Postgres and always shows me a blank line after the result. I need to remove these blank line because I make a cumulative report all days and the blank line must not appear. Here is an example code:

```
[user@machine ~/try]$ psql -t postgresql://user:pass@machine/conn << EOF
? SELECT version();
? EOF
 PostgreSQL 9.5.5 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3), 64-bit

[user@machine ~/try]$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want `psql` to be quiet, tell it to be:

```bash
~> psql --no-align --tuples-only --quiet --command='SELECT version()'
PostgreSQL 11.3 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 8.3.1 20190223 (Red Hat 8.3.1-2), 64-bit
~>
```

Comment: Thanks, with --quiet not works but with --no-aling not shows me blank line at the end